# Two disjoint closed sets $A,B$ with $B$ compact, show $d(A,B) > 0$ Verify my proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

Two disjoint closed sets $E,F$ with $E$ compact, show $d(E,F) > 0$.

So, with compactness we get a few things, that every sequence has a convergent subsequence and we can use the extreme value theorem. I saw a proof on this site where they use convergence of subsequences, but I'd like to see one using the extreme value theorem, as I'm sure is possible. Here is what I've came up with so far.

Proof: Define a function $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(e)=d(e,F)$. One can check that this function is continuous.

Since this is a continuous function on a compact set $E$, we can apply the extreme value theorem. Thus $x \in E$ s.t. $f(x) \leq f(e)$ $\forall e \in E$.

Since $E \cap F = \emptyset$ and $x \in E$ we have $d(x,F)>0$

Now i'm a bit stuck... Can anyone help out?... I have yet to use the fact that $F$ is closed.

Comment: Yes, I believe I can without much trouble, and yet even assuming this triviality my proof is not yet complete.

Comment: Yes, I've gotten that far already, as you can see above.

Comment: I misread; sorry.  How about: if $d(x,F)=0$ then $x\in F$ contrary to hypothesis.  Otherwise, $d(e,F)\ge f(x,F)>0$ for all $e$, so $d(E.F)>0$.

Comment: Ahh, right. I mean I wanted to get $d(E,F)$ in there somewhere, that's what was messing with me. But I couldn't say that $d(E,F) \geq d(x,F) > 0$,, but what you did was sort of like that, you said $d(e,F) \geq d(x,F) > 0$ for all $e$, which is kind of the same thing... There is some small technical detail that I feel like I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ is closed, so $x \notin F$ implies $d(x,F)>0$: As $x \in X\setminus F$ and the latter set is closed, there is some $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq X\setminus F$, which implies that when $y \in F$, $d(x,y) \ge r$.

So $d(x,F)=\inf\{d(x,y): y \in F\} \ge r >0$.

So after you applied that $f(x)=d(x,F)$ has a minimum $p \in E$ by compactness of $E$, the closedness of $F$ and the fact that $p \in E$ implies $p \notin F$ by disjointness, we have that $d(A,B) \ge f(p) >0$, finishing the proof.

Comment: Right, $p$ is in the complement of $F$, a closed set, so we can find an $\epsilon$ neighborhood. Thanks man!

Comment: So it's possible for $E$ to be compact, $E \cap F = \emptyset$, and then the minimum of our function at point $p$ to be in $F$ if $F$ is not closed???? But the sets are still disjoint, I'm confused how $p$ could ever be in $F$ whether $F$ is closed or not.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom The function $f$ is defined on $E$ so it has a minimum $p$ in $E$, by compactness. And of course $p \notin F$ as $E \cap F = \emptyset$. So then we can use that $F$ is closed in the final step.

Comment: Right, to show the distance is greater than zero, not to conclude that $ p \notin F$. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose $d(E,F)=0$. Then there exist $(e_n) \subset E,(f_n) \subset F$ with $d(e_n,f_n) \to 0$. $(e_n)$ has a subsequence $(e_{n_k})$ converging to some point $e \in E$. Now use triangle inequality to show that $(f_{n_k})$ also tends to $e$. But $F$ is closed so the limit of $(f_{n_k})$ must belong to $F$. Thus we get the contradiction that $e \in E \cap F$.

Alternatively, use your argument and just observe that $d(E,F)=\inf \{d(e,F): e \in E\}=f(x)=d(x,F) >0$.

Comment: Thank you sir. However, I was trying to prove it without passing to a subsequence, but rather exploiting the compactness of our set by appealing to the extreme value theorem. Do you know how to do the proof this way?

Comment: Also, in your comment, do you mean $(f_n)$ tends to $e$ rather than $(f_n_k)$?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom No we cannot show that $(f_n)$ tends to $e$. We only know that $(e_{n_k})$ tends to $e$.

Comment: Right, I'm sorry, i misread. You're answer makes me realize that I never used the fact that $F$ was closed in doing the proof the way I'm trying to do it.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom Your argument also works with just one  more observation. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, going from the $inf = f(x)$ had me a bit worried but it definitely makes sense, but only because of the extreme value theorem, awesome.